# zebra printer and cups "Printer drivers are deprecated" - how to solve?

Tags: drivers, printing, cups-lpd

I have a Zebra ZTC ZD421-300dpi ZPL printer, connected to a Raspberry. I initialize the printer as follows:

```
lpadmin -p zebra421 -E -v "usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20ZD421-300dpi%20ZPL?serial=MYSERIAL" -m "drv:///sample.drv/zebra.ppd"
```

When I do this, I get this message:

> lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a
> future version of CUPS.

This is the result which comes back from the command above, which makes trouble in my node script afterwards as this is stored as an error message that comes back from the command.

On this page: https://www.cups.org/doc/admin.html I read something about to try using `-m everywhere` instead of the actual driver:

```
lpadmin -p zebra421 -E -v "usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20ZD421-300dpi%20ZPL?serial= MYSERIAL" -m everywhere
```

But this results in:

> lpadmin: Unable to connect to "Zebra Technologies:0": Name or service
> not known

What can I do now? Can I somehow suppress that the message comes back from the command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and in the end installed the printer successfully with the following command:

```
sudo lpadmin -p Zebra -m "drv:///sample.drv/zebra.ppd" -D "Zebra ZD220" -E -v "usb://Zebra%20Technologies/ZTC%20ZD220-203dpi%20ZPL?serial=D4J223105324"
```

My guess is the order of these commands matter.

Hope this helps someone who ends up here having the same issue.